# Cannot differentiate between "Completed Items" and "Pending Items" on developer story

Tags: bug, design, developer-story, user-interface

Please make it more easily distinguishable between what is complete and what isn't on "Finish Your Profile" on the developer story.  ALL items have a check mark next to them yet I am presented with a "Hide completed items".

So initial list:

[image]

Upon clicking Hide Completed Items I get this:

[image]

My suggestion is to only place the check mark only if the items are actually complete.  Also I would re-word the last item, it doesn't sound right and at first seems a bit confusing.  Maybe change it to something like:

> "Add an optional assessment"

> Don't have enough rep?  No worries - you can show off your expertise by adding an assessment.